# Fine-grained way to measure infinity

Tags: vector-spaces, infinity

It is known that the cardinality of $R$ is equal to the cardinality of $R^2$, $R^3$, etc. But, intuitively these sets have different sizes. A possible way to formalize this intuition is to talk about the *dimension* of a set, seen as a vector-space over $R$. So $R$ has a dimension of 1, $R^2$ has a dimension of 2, etc.

My question is: what happens when we go to higher cardinalities? Specifically: what is the dimension of $2^{R^2}$, relative to $2^R$? Is there a way to define a basis  such that the dimension of $2^{R^k}$ is $k$ over that vector space?

Comment: We say that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ have the same cardinality by considereing bijective *maps* between these *sets*. We can distinguish there sizes (i.e. dimensions) if we consider less maps, namly only instead *linear maps between $\mathbb R$-spaces*.You would habve ot make $2^{\mathbb R}$ an $\mathbb R$ vector space in the first place to apply your notion of size - or explain what addition maps (but not all!), i.e. less rich structure than $\mathbb R$-space, are to be considered for such comparisions. Of course, $2^{\mathbb R}$ is a vetor space over $\mathbb F_2$ ...